# Fixed URL Injection in WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, url, code-injection

Since some days ago i have received some alerts from Google about errors in my web site, i had been fixed them, some about 404 errors.

But i really doesn't know what to do with the last one, is about an url injection in my site, i don't know how to fixed this.

The url reported is: http://www.4lytics.com/buckleya/illusioned/5994_1261/380buckleya/

I updated the CMS (WordPress) and delete some files I tried with some security plugins to find malware but it doesn't get anything.

What can i check far away from the things i made?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no such 404 error on  http://www.4lytics.com/buckleya/illusioned/5994_1261/380buckleya/ . There may be any css or js file is not loading properly.

Comment: The thing is that i havent nothing like buckleya or illusioned in post, pages or categories

Comment: You can confirm your malware by deactivating your plugins one by one.